# cordova how to display inital local version of cacheable content, if offline?

Tags: cordova

**Scenario**
With Cordova (3.4) / jquerymobile app, want to use appcache to check if there is new content for help info relevant to app, which will be displayed via navigation from index.html to help.html then available offline. Intention is to ship an initial copy of help.html with app.

index.html has help button click event:
    location.href = "http://ourdomain.com/something/help.html";

help.html (local copy shipped with app, and web version)

The manifest file just lists the help file, as we do not intend on updating index.html

**What does not work:**
If the first time the app is executed, and the device is offline, navigating to the help page results in "Webpage not available". No real surprise there.

**What works:**
If the app does have network connectivity when first launched, help info is cached when navigating to help screen and is subsequently available offline. New updates on webserver are reflected in app.

**Question:**
Is there a way if app is offline to check if the appcache is not populated yet for the desired help URL? Then if no appcache for the URL exists we either:
1) prepopulate cache with contents of a local help file, or
2) simply display the local file?

ta

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this can be helpful, but you can add an event listener to check when the device is offline:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);
document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);
```

You can also check if the appache is working with `window.applicationCache.status`

If it returns 0, then the page is not cached. If it is 1, it means that the application is running the latest version from the cached assets.